# Nlog not writing to ORACLE DATABASE .net 6.0 web app

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-6.0, nlog

I configured Nlog in my .NET 6 application and it is logging correctly to file and console however when I try to write to my ORACLE Database it throws the error of MISSING Select keyword in Nlog internal log file.

Below is my nlog.config file. I configured it using the example on github and changing the necessary DbProvider for ORACLE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\Temp\nlog-internal.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <!-- Database Target: Logs to Oracle Database -->
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"
            connectionString ="Data Source=DataSource;User Id=username;Password=pwd;"
            commandText ="insert into LogTable(Level, Message, CreatedOn, Exception, URL, Logger, Action) values(:level, :message, :date, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)"
            commandType ="Text">
            <parameter name="level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="message" layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="date" layout="${longdate}" dbType="DateTime"/>
            <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
            <parameter name="url" layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
            <parameter name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <parameter name="action" layout="${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Console Target: Logs to Console -->
    <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${message}" />
  <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore6-own.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|${callsite}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- Log all messages to database and console -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="off" final="true" />
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="off" final="true" />
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database,console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Below is the error in my nlog internal log file:

```
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3687 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Open connection.
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Executing Text: insert into LogTable(Level, Message, CreatedOn, Exception, URL, Logger, Action) values(:level, :message, :date, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'level' = 'Info' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'message' = 'Successfully fetched data' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'date' = '11/08/2023 07:45:15' (DateTime)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'exception' = '' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'url' = 'http://localhost/api/message/get' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'logger' = 'Controller' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'action' = 'GetPage' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.4523 Error DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Error when writing to database. Exception: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.ExecuteDbCommandWithParameters(LogEventInfo logEvent, IDbConnection dbConnection, IDbTransaction dbTransaction)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteLogEventSuppressTransactionScope(LogEventInfo logEvent, String connectionString)
```

Comment: Don't change the question to something else as it invalidates the existing answers. If you have a follow-on question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Sorry about that. Follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444302/nlog-not-writing-to-oracle-database-net-6-web-app-follow-up-question

Answer (score 2):

`LEVEL` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en//database/oracle/oracle-database/23/zzpre/Oracle-reserved-words-keywords-namespaces.html#GUID-25FE5FB4-5B17-4AFA-9B59-77B6036EF579) in Oracle that is used in hierarchical queries; you cannot use it as a column name without using a quoted identifier.

You should have found this when you tried to create the `LogTable` table.

If you do want to use `Level` as an identifier then surround it in double quotes and make sure you use the exact same case in the identifier as was used to define the table:

```sql
insert into LogTable("LEVEL", Message, CreatedOn, Exception, URL, Logger, Action)
  values(:level, :message, :date, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)
```

A better solution would be to not use reserved words as column names and then you can continue to use unquoted identifiers.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S7TChiT8)

Comment: I created the table via dotnet migration so it did not throw an error for that there however with changing the column name to LogLevel as using double quotes in nlog.config was showing an error in the file itself, it now threw a new error in the nlog internal file ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name. will update question accordingly