# Nlog not writing to ORACLE Database .net 6 web app (follow up question)

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-6.0, nlog

I configured Nlog in my .NET 6 application and it is logging correctly to file and console however when I try to write to my ORACLE Database it throws the error of table or view does not exist (while my table is present in the database) in Nlog internal log file.

Below is my nlog.config file. I configured it using the example on github and changing the necessary DbProvider for ORACLE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\Temp\nlog-internal.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <!-- Database Target: Logs to Oracle Database -->
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"
            connectionString ="Data Source=DataSource;User Id=username;Password=pwd;"
            commandText ="insert into LogTable(LogLevel, Message, CreatedOn, Exception, URL, Logger, Action) values(:level, :message, :createddate, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)"
            commandType ="Text">
            <parameter name="level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="message" layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="createddate" layout="${longdate}" dbType="DateTime"/>
            <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
            <parameter name="url" layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
            <parameter name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <parameter name="action" layout="${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Console Target: Logs to Console -->
    <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${message}" />
  <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore6-own.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|${callsite}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- Log all messages to database and console -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="off" final="true" />
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="off" final="true" />
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database,console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Below is the error in my nlog internal log file:

```
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3687 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Open connection.
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Executing Text: insert into LogTable(LogLevel, Message, CreatedOn, Exception, URL, Logger, Action) values(:level, :message, :createddate, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'level' = 'Info' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'message' = 'Successfully fetched data' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3756 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'createddate' = '11/08/2023 07:45:15' (DateTime)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'exception' = '' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'url' = 'http://localhost/api/message/get' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'logger' = 'Controller' (String)
2023-11-08 07:45:15.3910 Trace   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'action' = 'GetPage' (String)
2023-11-08 09:25:12.2648 Error DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Error when writing to database. Exception: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.ExecuteDbCommandWithParameters(LogEventInfo logEvent, IDbConnection dbConnection, IDbTransaction dbTransaction)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteLogEventSuppressTransactionScope(LogEventInfo logEvent, String connectionString)
2023-11-08 09:25:12.2648 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Close connection because of error
2023-11-08 09:25:12.2648 Trace DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Close connection (KeepConnection = false).
```

Verified connection string as the same in appsettings.json file and Table is also created inside the database, image below
[Table is present in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETNLo.png)

Comment: yes connecting as the table owner

Comment: Upon looking into the database further hovering over the Table shows it as HPJZEDI.LogTable@HPJZMWDB-UAT now when i put that into the commandText the error in the nlog-internal file changes to 'ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword',
the command executed is : 'insert into HPJZEDI.LogTable@HPJZMWDB-UAT(LogLevel, Message, CreatedOn, Exception, URL, Logger, Action) values(:loglevel, :message, :createddate, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)'

Comment: Don't do that; your client is just trying to be help you know where you are, it shouldn't be part of the query. (It's actually complaining about the `-`, but quoting that too as `...@"HPJZMWDB-UAT"` would still be wrong - it would try to use a database link, with a still-illegal name, and which doesn't exist anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

According to the image you included, you have created the log table with the [quoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) `"LogTable"` - otherwise it would appear in the data dictionary as `LOGTABLE`, not `LogTable`.

If you have a quoted identifier then you need to quote all references to it, so your insert would be `insert into "LogTable"(...`, possibly also with quoted column names if that's how you defined the table: `insert into "LogTable"("LogLevel", "Message", ...`.

But that means you need to change your XML so you don't have to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534409/266304) those double quote characters:

```
commandText = 'insert into "LogTable"("LogLevel", "Message", "CreatedOn", "Exception", "URL", "Logger", "Action") values(:level, :message, :createddate, :exception, :url, :logger, :action)'
```

Quoted identifiers are generally a pain to work with, so if you have the option, I would suggest you drop and recreate your table without them; i.e. instead of

```
create table "LogTable" ("LogLevel" ...
```

do

```
create table LogTable (LogLevel ...
```

... and then your original (unquoted) insert statement will work.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I did have to change the xml.